# How to fetch whole string from start of comma to next comma or newline when "/" occurs in string

Tags: python, regex

I have string in format

```
,xys=2/3,
d=e,
b*y,
b/e
```

I want to fetch `xys=2/3` and `b/e`.

Right now I have regular expression which just picks `2/3` and `b/e`.

```
 pattern = r'(\S+)\s*(?<![;|<|#])/\s*(\S+)'
 regex = re.compile(pattern,re.DOTALL)
 for result in regex.findall(data):
     f.write("Division   " + str(result)+ "\n\n\n")
```

How can I modify to pick what I intend to do?

Comment: `(?:,).*(?:,)|.*/.*\n`

Comment: If you also have numbers with commas in your divisions, the task gets a little bit trickier.

Comment: I think *when `/` occurs in string*  should actually be *when "/" occurs on a **line***. And the second match should be `"\nb/e"`, right?

Comment: the string can be on same line . all string r separated by ",". when string have "/" we need to capture it

Comment: `x.split(",")[1].split('\n')[0] if "," in x[:-1] else None` - I have added a short explanation in answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Match anything but `,` (or newlines) up until the first slash `/`: `[^,/\n]*/`
- Match the remaining text up to the next comma: `[^,\n]*`
- Put the two together: `[^,/\n]*/[^,\n]*`

Answer (score 0):

No need for regular expressions.

```
s = """,xys=2/3,
d=e,
b*y,
b/e
"""
l = s.split("\n")

for line in l:
    if '/' in line:
        print(line.strip(","))
```

Comment: it possible the string can be on same line so it can be on same line a/2,b=e

Comment: Not in your question. Please edit it so the example tells us everything necessary to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
x.split(",")[1].split('\n')[0] if "," in x[:-1] else None
```

It ignores (evaluates to None) unles `,` is present in the non-last position, else extract the part between `,` and another `,` or till the end, and again filter until new line if any.